# In JPQL, how do you access properties of named parameters?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I'm using Hibernate 3.5.4-Final.

I want to pass an entity as a parameter of a named query, and then access a persisted property of that named parameter *in* that query. I want to do this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "hello", query = "SELECT p FROM WorkPackage p WHERE p IN (:workPackage).relatedWorkflows")
```

The problem is near the end of the query, in the

```
(:workPackage).relatedWorkflows
```

which causes Hibernate to throw a deploy-time QuerySyntaxException. Remove the parentheses doesn't help; I left them in for clarity. Is there any way around this, or am I going to have to do this programmatically?

Comment: FWIW Works perfectly fine in DataNucleus. A parameter can be of any type, and consequently fields can be referenced in the same way as fields of the candidate entity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. You have to pass the property value itself to the query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "hello", query = "SELECT p FROM WorkPackage p WHERE p IN (:relatedWorkflows)")

query.setParameterList("relatedWorkflows", workPackage.getRelatedWorkflows());
```